# How to refer to dict key

Tags: python

Here is a code of a link handler:

```
link_patterns = {'http[s]?://www.facebook.[a-z]{2,3}/[A-Za-z0-9\.]*/videos/([0-9]+)*/':Facebook.get_video()}
def find_pattern(url):
    for pattern in link_patterns:
        if re.match(pattern, url):
            return link_patterns[pattern]
    return None
```

How to call `Facebook.get_video()` with id argument fetched by regex from `link_patterns` dict key?

Comment: Is the "id" you refer to one of the capturing groups you have in the URL? Which group? Do all of your other potential patterns have IDs that can be accessed the same way (e.g. the same group number)?

Comment: @blckknght Yes. First group. Other patterns have IDs, I am not sure if they will have same group number.

Comment: You may want to use named capturing groups, so that the code can reliably get the right group group. They look like `(?P<groupname>stuff\d+)`.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 version:

```
link_patterns = {'http[s]?://www.facebook.[a-z]{2,3}/[A-Za-z0-9\.]*/videos/(vb.[0-9]+/){0,1}([0-9]+)*/':Facebook.get_video}
    def find_pattern(url):
        for pattern, action in link_patterns.items():
            matches = re.match(pattern, url)
            if matches:
                return matches.group(1), action
                # or capture group that contains id in your case
        return None

id, action = find_pattern(url)
if id:
    action(id)
```

You can return a function object and then call it with id as a parameter